# How to refer to another element within the same list?

Tags: r

I am trying to refer to another element within the same list without much success.

For example:

```
sample.list <- c(file.name = "AA", col.names = "AA")
```

I would like to replace the "AA" in the col.names element with the first element: file.name
This is because the file.name can be changed for other lists.  How can I do it?

Thanks

Jin

Comment: It's not clear what your intent is. Perhaps you need to show the input and the output you are looking for.

Comment: My intention is use this sample.list as a template, and store the file name and column names of the file in the same list.  I only would like to refer to the file name once, and it's in the file.name element.  Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: `c()` makes a vector, not a list.

Comment: This is an XY-question-problem. Saying what is not working but not saying what the overall goal might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the solution is pretty simple.

```
sample.list <- list(file.name = "AA")
sample.list <- list(sample.list, col.names = names(sample.list$file.name))
```

Thanks everybody for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
samplelist<-list(filename=c("A","B","C"), colnames=c("C1","C2","C3"))

samplelist[["colnames"]][1]<-samplelist[["filename"]][1]

> samplelist
$filename
[1] "A" "B" "C"

$colnames
[1] "A"  "C2" "C3"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I think my problem statement is not clear.  I figured out a way.  Sorry about that...